# How can I access to the IP camera connected to a subnetwork of a router without port forwarding?

Tags: python, connection, streaming, router

I'm struggling with some kind of connection problem.
Here's the problem that I wanted to resolve

---

What I want to do is getting video streaming data from a IP camera (RTSP)
The IP camera is attached to the router which has access to the internet
I want to connect to this IP camera from remote computer.

IP cam --- Router --- Internet --- My computer

I know that I can do this by setting port forwarding option of the router.
However, I cannot set the option because the router is not mine, which means I cannot access to the router's admininstration server (192.168.0.1)

I'm trying to figure out this issue by connecting a small edge computer (e.g., raspberry pi) to the router's subnetwork and send streaming data to my computer through the Internet.

IP cam --------- Router --- Internet --- My computer
minicomputer ---

It's certain that the minicomputer can access to my computer through ssh, so I think It's possible to use the minicom as a proxy.
What is the best the way to get the IP camera's streaming in my circumstance?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good idea would be to use a VPN. Install a VPN-Server (openvpn, wireguard, etc...) on your minicomputer in the same network as your camera. Than connect to your vpn from your computer. Now you should be able to access the camera.
I have a few ideas how to view the camera stream, depending how you would normaly access it.

1. If it is a software to connect to the camera, install a desktop-environment on your minicomputer and connect to it via VNC (more or less a linux equivalent to rdp on windows) or RDP. Then open the software and view your stream. It could be a bit laggy because it has to be transmitted two times (camera -> minipc -> your pc)
2. If you can access the stream via a url, you could setup a webserver (nginx or apache2) on your minicomputer and build a small html website, that displays the stream. This should be more perfomant than the first solution, but involves a bit more tinkering. If you should decide to use this solution, I should have an example HTML-Page somewhere. Just let me know and i will try to find it and share it.
3. Depending on how you setup your VPN-Server maybe you can connect to your Camera directly via it's IP. To do that, your VPN-Server has to do some routing between the subnets.

I know these are just some Ideas from the top of my head, but I hope I can help a bit. If you have more questions or I didn't explain it in a way it is understandable, feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

Install a vpn client on the minicomputer (wireguard is great). Then use ncat to establish an independent tunnel against each camera's rtsp port you want to access (each listening in its own port of course). Then point your rtsp client to your mini computer's vpn ip address and mentioned ports from any computer also connected to the named vpn.